# Attempted to invoke (method ID) on `Networking` (NativeModule name) with an invalid bridge

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

when I run my react native project on ios simulator, I get some warnings:
`Attempted to invoke (method ID) on Networking (NativeModule name) with an invalid bridge.` and `Attempted to invoke (method ID) on AlertManager (NativeModule name) with an invalid bridge.`

in my code only called an api and then received above warning